# Can't change volume in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This may be a possible dublicate...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/436594/everytime-i-start-ubuntu-or-change-sound-settings-my-volume-is-put-to-100

I can't change my volume anymore using Fn+Left/Right on the Keyboard (MSI GS70)
But all other Fn Keys work

In the sound settings there are no speakers or headphones listed, so I can't adjust volume through ubuntu settings...

The strange thing is, I have sound. But it's set too 100% since startup. That's basically no problem but it's really annoying to get shocked by the Ubuntu startup sound everytime I use my laptop

My Laptop has a 5.1 sorround sound card (I think the sound card is Creative X-Fi Sound Blaster) with two speakers and one internal microphone

So, I noticed, pulseaudio isn't loaded, whenever I run the command "pulseaudio" I get:

```
keksarmee@KeksLinux:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] module-ladspa-sink.c: Master sink not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink" (argument:"sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Konnte Daemon nicht initialisieren.
```

The last line is German and means "Couldn't initialize Daemon"

"pulseaudio --start" returns:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Start des Daemons fehlgeschlagen.
```

Which means "couldn't start Daemon"

I tried `sudo apt-get install -reinstall alsa alsa-base pulseaudio` and I tried to add pulseaudio to autostart list, but it still doesn't work

The pulseaudio volume application displays:

[image]

And pulse/client.conf is this:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BNFGWPqX

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Keks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it using the following steps:

1. Removed ~/.config/pulse directory.
2. Started Pulse Audio.

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
   pulseaudio --start
   ```

Incase if its still showing errors you will have to reinstall pulse audio and equalizer.

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio pulseaudio-equalizer
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
pulseaudio --start
```