# My volume is either max volume or muted, no middle ground

Tags: gnome, sound, volume-control

Asus Zenbook UX550, running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

Like the title says, my volume is either max or muted. I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548393/cant-change-volume-in-ubuntu-14-04), but nothing helped. In fact, prior to applying that fix, I could hear the volume indicator noises, now I can't even hear those. (By indicator noises, I mean those beeps that are made when adjusting the volume via keyboard).

Answer (score 18):

I have the same laptop and couldn't get volume control work well for a long time. Any level of volume was at the highest volume of the laptop speakers so I used it always on mute. This issue only affected speakers and not headphones (from plug or bluetooth).

I found a working solution based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022316/asus-zenbook-pro-ux550ve-sound-either-muted-or-very-loud):

1. Edit the file `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common` (with sudo):

`sudo vi /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common`

2. Add the following lines before the `[Element PCM] block`:

`[Element Master]
    switch = mute
    volume = ignore`

3. Kill the running daemon:

`pulseaudio -k`

After this steps I got the volume level working for my speakers. I assume a new daemon started automatically after killing the runnig daemon. If the daemon does not start, try to start it manually with:

`pulseaudio -D`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This recommendation has also worked on my ASUS Zenbook UM-431 laptop. Thanks @manuelmatas! It was helpfull!

Comment: Also confirmed for Zenbook UX490UA using Mint 20

Comment: Works on my Asus Zenbook UX430 as well. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Works perfect on Asus ROG Strix G17 G712LW. Many thanks

Comment: Does not work on Asus rog strix

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my UX550 until I activated two bottom speakers.

`apt install alsa-tools-gui`

`hdajackretask`

Select a codec: Realtek ALC295

Click **Show unconnected pins**

Then you need to override `Pin ID: 0x1b` and `Pin ID: 0x1e` and select `Internal speaker (Back)` or `Internal speaker (LFE)` - I didn't noticed any difference between them.

Next click `Apply now` and `Install boot override`.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well! However, whenever I plug in headphones, all I hear is a repeating popping sound. Did you experience anything similar? Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: No, I didn't have such issue with my headphones. But I'm using Linux Mint 18.3, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: How did you come up with these settings? I get no sound with these settings on UX550VD.

Comment: @rustyx I noticed, that only 2 out of 4 speakers were active. So I launched the hdajackretask and activated all other "Internal speakers" that the GUI showed. That's it.