# snd-hda-intel model for UBUNTU 20.04 installed in an ASUS ROG STRIX G15 (G512)

Tags: 20.04, alsa, asus

Has anyone succeeded in configuring properly the ALSA drivers in an ASUS G512 running Ubuntu 20.04?
More particularly, is there any model ID that would make it work once specified in the ***alsa-base.conf*** file?

I've seen in a related post that ***options snd-hda-intel model= asus-zenbook*** was suggested. For me, it allows to get sound through the internal speakers, but without volume control, and with the sound jack only allowing sound output but no mic entrance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. I had no speakers and made them work with options snd-hda-intel model= asus-zenbook. Just like you, I had no volume control after this fix.
Just discovered this for volume control: [My volume is either max volume or muted, no middle ground](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973690/my-volume-is-either-max-volume-or-muted-no-middle-ground)
Volume control works fine now for speakers. Finally, when using headphones volume was too low, but solved that running alsamixer in terminal and setting volume as desired.
I am not sure if both fixes are necessary or only second one. When trying it seems to work both ways now.

Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon on Asus ROG Strix Scar 15.

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic at this site. Your solution may work on Ubuntu, it is obvious enough ;-) But please post answers tested on Ubuntu.