# Built-in speakers of Thinkpad X1 Carbon don't change volume with Ubuntu 18 and 19

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad

I bought a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (7th generation), and decided to install Ubuntu.

At first I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed that neither the volume buttons nor the graphical slider of the GNOME desktop were able to change the volume of the built-in speakers. Devices connected to the audio output (like headphones or external speakers) worked just fine, and the volume could be easily controlled from the keyboard and from graphical sliders.

Given this problem, I tried to install Ubuntu 19.10 to see if something would change, but the same problems persisted:

- Pressing the volume-up and volume-down keys triggers the usual feedback sound and animation; the animation changes correctly, but the sound is always the same (quite loud, by the way) when using the built-in speakers.
- When using headphones, everything works perfectly.
- Pressing the mute key correctly mutes the sound, both with built-in speakers and with headphones.
- Pressing the volume-down key many times to the end correctly mutes the sound, both with built-in speakers and with headphones.
- As a side note, I had previously installed Arch Linux on this machine; I hope I didn't mess up something related to the built-in speakers when trying to install it.

I tried following [this solution,](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107735) but nothing changed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try Workaround from arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in a comment to the question, a solution is to follow the patches about audio on Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th gen. suggested in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)#Audio): configure Ubuntu to 4.0 audio output (instead of 2.0); edit `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common` by adding the following above `[Element PCM]`:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

Then reboot.

Comment: working on my x1 carbon 8gen with Lubuntu 20.04